# No option to add delegate

Tags: xcode, uitableview, interface-builder

[image]

[image]

I select the circle with the square and then drag from `Referencing Outlets` onto a table view but there's no option to set the delegate or data source.

Why isn't this option available?

Here is a wider view when the table view is selected.

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't you reference *from* the tableview?

Comment: Sounds like a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

You have to select your `UITableView` object in interface builder and drag `delegate` and `dataSource` to fileOwner.
[image]

Comment: I've added a screen shot. I don't have the outlet types on the right or the File's Owner on the left.

Comment: There's a hide/show button on on the right of outlets (https://www.dropbox.com/s/i2owmbyyjq3wifw/Screenshot%202015-11-03%2021.34.57.png?dl=0). And the destination should be here not a "file owner" but "detail" on a "detail scene" cause you're using storyboard, not XIB.

Comment: I don't get the Outlets section. Its not there. With a new project this stuff seems to to work just fine. Perhaps its because my table view is added to a detail view. Anyhow I've hooked these things up in code for now.